# Spring Boot Application hanging on shutdown after running Async methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have found that my spring boot application that implements `ApplicationRunner` hangs when trying to shut down. It appears to be caused by when `@Async` annotated methods have been executed.

I have a `MainComponent` and `JobService` classes:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class AsyncJobsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AsyncJobsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
@Component
public class MainComponent implements ApplicationRunner {

    private final JobsService jobsService;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        final List<AtomicInteger> counters = IntStream.range(0, 1).mapToObj(value -> new AtomicInteger(0)).toList();
        final List<Future<Void>> futures = counters.stream().map(this.jobsService::doTask).toList();

        boolean complete = false;
        while (!complete) {
            plotCounter(counters);
            Thread.sleep(250);
            complete = futures.stream().map(Future::isDone).reduce((aBoolean, aBoolean2) -> aBoolean && aBoolean2).get();
        }
        plotCounter(counters);

        System.out.println("Complete.");

    }

    private void plotCounter(final List<AtomicInteger> counters) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counters.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("Counter %d - %d%s", i, counters.get(i).get(), System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@Log4j2
public class JobsService {

    @Async
    public Future<Void> doTask(final AtomicInteger counter) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 3000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
        return new AsyncResult<>(null);
    }
}
```

All the tasks complete successfully but the application takes sometime to terminate after the final `System.out.println()` call.

This is executing on Linux Mint with Open-JDK 17.0.7 but it also does the same on a RaspberryPi.

A full demo application is here: [async-jobs-demo](https://github.com/jtkb/async-jobs)

Comment: Please check above answers. Basically your asynchronous runner returns without any delay but your application will wait until all threads completed. Unless you call the close() method directly.

Comment: @Mar-Z yes it did. Specifically I needed to change the `main()` method to call the `close()` method.